# Segmentation Fault with Pointers and Structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

This program is supposed to manipulate a student list. Every time I try to add more than one student I get a segmentation fault error. Also, when I try to print the list recursively I get a segmentation fault error. I think it has to do with how I am saving to the structure and/or calling it. I am very new to programming so I'm sure it is something simple. Any ideas?

```
//Header file declarations.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Structure defintion.
struct student {
   int ID;
   char name[40];
   struct student *next;
};

//Type definition.
typedef struct student Student;

//Function prototypes.
int getChoice();
Student *addToList(Student *List);
void printList(Student *List);
void printListRR(Student *List);
void searchList(Student *List);

/*main function
Objective: This function provides runs a function call based on an option selected the user in another function.
Input: This function recieves no input from the user directly but it is passed their menu selection.
Output: The function outputs error messages and a closing salutation to the user. It returns 0.
*/ 
int main(void) {
    int choice = 0;
    Student *SLIST = NULL;

    //Call getChoice to get user's selection 
    choice = getChoice();

    //Switch-case for the possible menu selections 
    while(choice >= 0) {
        switch(choice) {
            case 0 : printf("Bye...\n"); exit(0);
            case 1 : SLIST = addToList(SLIST); break;
            case 2 : printList(SLIST); break;
            case 3 : printListRR(SLIST); break;
            case 4 : searchList(SLIST); break;
            default: printf("That is not a valid choice\n");
        }
        choice = getChoice();
    }

    if(SLIST) free(SLIST);
    return 0;
}

int getChoice() {
    int choice = 0;

    printf("\n****** MENU ******\n");
    printf("1. Add new student to list.\n");
    printf("2. Print the student list, beginning to end.\n");
    printf("3. Recursively print the student list from the end.\n");
    printf("4. Search the list for a student.\n");
    printf("0. Quit.\n");
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    return choice;
}

Student *addToList(Student *List){

    Student *studentPtr = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student));

    printf("Student ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &(studentPtr->ID));
    printf("Student Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", studentPtr->name);

    if(List == NULL){
        return studentPtr;
        }

    Student *nextStudent = List;

    while (nextStudent->next != NULL){
        nextStudent = nextStudent->next;
    }

    nextStudent->next = studentPtr;

    return List;
}

void printList(Student *List){
    while(List != NULL){
        printf("%d %s\n", List->ID, List->name);
        List = List->next;
    }
}

void printListRR(Student *List){
    if(List == NULL){
        return;
    }

    printListRR(List->next);
}

void searchList(Student *List){
    int idSearch;

    printf("Enter student ID to search for: ");
    scanf("%d", &idSearch);

    while(List != NULL){
        if(List->ID == idSearch){
            printf("%d %s\n", List->ID, List->name);
            return;
        }
        List = List->next;
    }
    printf("ID %d not found", idSearch);
}
```

Comment: Compile your program with `-g` option and run it under debugger. When the program crashes, the debugger will tell you which line of code caused the crash. You will also be able to explore the values of all variables at the moment of crash. Hopefully, this information will help you to answer your question.

Comment: You need to initialise the `next` element to `NULL` when you create a new list entry (via `malloc`).

Comment: IOW, put `studentPtr->next = NULL;` after the (unchecked) scanf for your student name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initialising studentPtr->next to NULL in addToList()?